# Count Similar Div : Simple html dom

Tags: php, html

I have a html layout like :

```
<div id="pageno">1</div>
<div id="pageno">2</div>
<div id="pageno">3</div>
<div id="pageno">4</div>
<div id="pageno">5</div>
```

I need to know using html dom parser how can i know the last div inner text?

THanks in advance

Comment: this is not valid HTML because all of the divs have the same id, replace the id with a class instead.

Comment: Are you talking about [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: this is a valid html code no doubt about it...i just need to know how may div are holding similar id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a new DomDocument.
$dom = new DomDocument();

// Load your HTML into it.
$dom->loadHTML('
<div id="pageno">1</div>
<div id="pageno">2</div>
<div id="pageno">3</div>
<div id="pageno">4</div>
<div id="pageno">5</div>
');

// Obtain a list of the DIVs.
$divList = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");

// Obtain the last element of the list.
$lastDiv = $divList->item($divList->length - 1);

// Output the inner text.
echo $lastDiv->nodeValue;
```

However, the HTML you have provided is not valid, as element IDs should be unique. This may cause an error in the `loadHTML` function.